# To Find One Data Member when another data member is given

Tags: c++, class, pointer-to-member

Consider a class named ball such that it has two data members radius and color can anyone help me to write a function that accepts radius as the input and provides the color of the ball as the output. 
There can be balls of more than one color for the same radius

I have created an array of objects where the details of all the balls are given by the user during run time

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;
 class ball
 {
 public:
 int rad;
 string col;
 void read()
{
    cin>>rad;
    cin>>col;

}
void out()
{
    cout<<rad<<" ";
    cout<<col<<" ";
}

};
 int main()
  {
     ball *b;
     int n,i;
     cin>>n;

     b=new(ball[n]);
     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      b[i].read();

}
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to map a radius to a colour? Or is it just random? What is your domain of colours?

Comment: Use a standard container (like the templated `std::vector` from standard header `<vector>` to store a dynamically allocated collection of balls, rather using operator `new` directly.   Read up on standard algorithms (part of the C++ standard library) too - there are a number of algorithms that can be used to find an element of a container that meets some criterion.

Comment: @Peter good advice but OP may be doing an exercise and not allowed to do that. They should edit the question to add more detail about what they are trying to achieve

Comment: I would try with std::multimap

Comment: @paisanco - If the OP had said something like that, I wouldn't have bothered with the advice.   But I do agree this question reads like a homework exercise - which is why, at most, I would give pointers to help the OP learn, but not a solution as such.

Comment: @Ardent Coder what I want to do is input the radius and colours for n balls.                                       Suppose n=2 radius 2  colour red.        Radius 5 colour blue then I want to write a function where input will be 2 and the output should be red

Comment: @ClarenceCallahan *Re: "what I want to do is input the radius and colours for n balls"* You should edit your question with what you've said just now. It's completely different from how your question is phrased currently. And add that example while making the edit, cuz that makes your intentions more clear.